# How to select 2 objects from 2 tables in one query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I want to get the below result in one query by linq methods such as `.Where`, `.Select` etc., is it possible?

Inner join is the better.

```cs
new {
    Blog = MyDbContext.Blogs.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Url == "xxx.com"),
    Post = MyDbContext.Posts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Blog.Url == "xxx.com" &&
                                                  p.Author == "Jack")
}
```

Models:

```cs
public class Blog 
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post 
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any SQL.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ans = MyDbContext.Blogs.Where(b => b.Url == "xxx.com")
                           .Select(b => new {
                                   Blog = b,
                                   Post = b.Posts.Where(p => p.Author == "Jack").FirstOrDefault()
                            })
                            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: `'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'SingleOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.`.  How to avoid Client Evaluation ?

Comment: @JokeHuang I changed it to use `FirstOrDefault` - this will prevent an exception if there are multiple matches but perhaps evaluate server side. If you need the exception, you will have to split the query and add the `SingleOrDefault` on the client side. I assume the last `SingleOrDefault` is handled by EF Core properly.